# Style won't load for Ubuntu SDK apps

Tags: 15.10, ubuntu-sdk, qt5

I have recently performed a fresh install of Ubuntu 15.10. However, the preinstalled webbrowser-app's look is corrupted. I have found out that the style is not loading, however I can't solve this problem myself. This is what appears in the terminal when launching the webbrowser-app (As my language is Polish, you may find helpful, that the "Brak dostępu" is similar to English "Access denied"/"Permission denied" etc.):

```
QInotifyFileSystemWatcherEngine::addPaths: inotify_add_watch failed: Brak dostępu
file:///usr/share/webbrowser-app/webbrowser/Browser.qml:643:13: QML Button: Warning: Style ButtonStyle.qml not found in theme 
file:///usr/share/webbrowser-app/webbrowser/Suggestions.qml:85:5: QML Scrollbar: Warning: Style ScrollbarStyle.qml not found in theme 
file:///usr/share/webbrowser-app/webbrowser/AddressBar.qml:69:5: QML TextField: Warning: Style TextFieldStyle.qml not found in theme 
file:///usr/share/webbrowser-app/ChromeBase.qml:53:5: QML ThinProgressBar: Warning: Style ProgressBarStyle.qml not found in theme 
file:///usr/share/webbrowser-app/InvalidCertificateErrorSheet.qml:169:13: QML Button: Warning: Style ButtonStyle.qml not found in theme 
file:///usr/share/webbrowser-app/InvalidCertificateErrorSheet.qml:159:13: QML Button: Warning: Style ButtonStyle.qml not found in theme 
file:///usr/share/webbrowser-app/ErrorSheet.qml:52:9: QML Button: Warning: Style ButtonStyle.qml not found in theme 
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Label.qml:58: TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Label.qml:58: TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Label.qml:58: TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Button.qml:108: TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultFont' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Button.qml:103: TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultGradient' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Button.qml:92: TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultColor' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Label.qml:58: TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Label.qml:58: TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Label.qml:58: TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Label.qml:58: TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Label.qml:58: TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Label.qml:58: TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Label.qml:58: TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Label.qml:58: TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Label.qml:58: TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Label.qml:58: TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Label.qml:58: TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Button.qml:108: TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultFont' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Button.qml:103: TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultGradient' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Button.qml:92: TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultColor' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Button.qml:108: TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultFont' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Button.qml:103: TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultGradient' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Label.qml:58: TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of null
file:///usr/share/webbrowser-app/ChromeButton.qml:29: TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of null
file:///usr/share/webbrowser-app/ChromeButton.qml:29: TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/TextField.qml:946: TypeError: Cannot read property 'normal' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/TextField.qml:987: TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectionColor' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/TextField.qml:986: TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectedTextColor' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/TextField.qml:841: TypeError: Cannot read property 'frameSpacing' of null
file:///usr/share/webbrowser-app/ChromeButton.qml:29: TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of null
file:///usr/share/webbrowser-app/ChromeButton.qml:29: TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of null
file:///usr/share/webbrowser-app/ChromeButton.qml:29: TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Button.qml:108: TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultFont' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Button.qml:103: TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultGradient' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Button.qml:92: TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultColor' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Label.qml:58: TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Label.qml:58: TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Label.qml:58: TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Label.qml:58: TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of null
file:///usr/share/webbrowser-app/webbrowser/NewTabViewWide.qml:290:9: QML Sections: Warning: Style SectionsStyle.qml not found in theme 
file:///usr/share/webbrowser-app/webbrowser/NewTabViewWide.qml:276:5: QML Scrollbar: Warning: Style ScrollbarStyle.qml not found in theme 
file:///usr/share/webbrowser-app/webbrowser/NewTabViewWide.qml:232:5: QML Scrollbar: Warning: Style ScrollbarStyle.qml not found in theme 
file:///usr/share/webbrowser-app/webbrowser/NewTabViewWide.qml:136:5: QML Scrollbar: Warning: Style ScrollbarStyle.qml not found in theme 
qml: Loaded 3 UA override(s) from     file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Web/ua-overrides-desktop.js
[1125/210824:ERROR:connection.cc(1321)] Cookie sqlite error 14, errno -2: unable to open database file, sql: -- sqlite3_open()
[1125/210824:ERROR:connection.cc(1321)] Cookie sqlite error 14, errno -2: unable to open database file, sql: -- sqlite3_open()
[1125/210824:ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(129)] Failed to create directory: /home/mitu/.cache/webbrowser-app/Cache2
[1125/210824:ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(574)] Simple Cache Backend: wrong file structure on disk: /home/mitu/.cache/webbrowser-app/Cache2
[1125/210824:ERROR:cache_util.cc(132)] Unable to move cache folder /home/mitu/.cache/webbrowser-app/Cache2 to /home/mitu/.cache/webbrowser-app/old_Cache2_000
[1125/210824:ERROR:cache_creator.cc(132)] Unable to create cache
[1125/210824:ERROR:layer_tree_host_impl.cc(2121)] Forcing zero-copy tile initialization as worker context is missing
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/ListItems/1.3/Base.qml:173:5: QML ProgressionVisual: Warning: Style ProgressionVisualStyle.qml not found in theme 
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/ListItems/1.3/Empty.qml:294: TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/ListItems/1.3/ThinDivider.qml:57: TypeError: Cannot read property 'normal' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/1.3/Label.qml:58: TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of null
[1125/210825:ERROR:channel.cc(307)] RawChannel read error (connection broken)
```

Have anyone encountered such problems. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I managed to get it. Somehow the directory "~/.config/ubuntu-ui-toolkit" belonged to user root and group root, therefore apps could not read which theme to use. After reassigning this directory to my user applications start properly.

Comment: Any theory as to why this would happen? I've only experienced it in a chroot so far.